# Why PHP if..esleif..else starts from beginning again after MySQL query in it

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, if-statement

I am using following code to run update query if value is not duplicate in database.

```
if($lastvote==false){ // There isn't duplicate entry, just run INSERT query.
    $this->save();
    return "Vote recorded!";
}elseif($lastvote=="down" && $this->vote_value=="down"){
    return "Already voted down!";
}elseif($lastvote=="up" && $this->vote_value=="up"){
    return "Already voted up!";
}elseif($lastvote=="up" && $this->vote_value=="down"){
    $this->update_last($this->topic_id, $this->updated_by, $this->vote_value);
    return "Vote changed to down!";
}elseif($lastvote=="down" && $this->vote_value=="up"){
    $this->update_last($this->topic_id, $this->updated_by, $this->vote_value);
    return "Vote changed to up!";
}
```

The queries works well. But after function

> $this->update_last()

```
private function update_last($topic, $by, $value){
    global $database;
    $sql = "UPDATE ".static::$table_name." SET vote_value='".$value."' WHERE topic_id = ".$topic." AND updated_by = ".$by;
    $database->query($sql);
    return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

it is not returning "Vote changed to up/down" as per last two conditions. Rather it returning "Already voted up/down" from first two queries after successfully executing the UPDATE query from last two conditions.

Please guide me where I am making mistake?

Comment: Most likely this is an issue with your script getting called _twice_ in a row. This would explain 1. the missing output and 2. the unexpected output. Check your http servers access log file, you will see the processed requests there.

Comment: @arkascha I have checked apache access log file. But didn't found any error. But after commenting the update query in update_last() function and just returning true. I get the right return value from above function. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the same result writing:

```
if($lastvote==false){ // There isn't duplicate entry, just run INSERT query.
    $this->save();
    return "Vote recorded!";
}

if ( $lastvote == $this->vote_value )  return "Already voted $lastvote!";

$this->update_last($this->topic_id, $this->updated_by, $this->vote_value);
return "Vote changed to $this->vote_value!";
```

If the error persists you need to check the actual value of `$lastvote` and `$this->vote_value` to see what values you are comparing.

Comment: Thank you for simplification. But still getting the ``Already voted $lastvote!`` return value, after successfully executing the ``$this->update_last()`` function. Not **Vote changed to $this->vote_value!**.
I get the right return message, if I disable the update query and just try to return the ``true`` from ``update_last()`` function.

Comment: There is something else wrong with your code. The result of `$this->update()` is not even checked, right now. So whether it returns `true` or `false` the `return` message is always sent. Do you have debugging enabled?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging I made it work.

When I extracted if conditions to frontend from class.php file it works. Now I am using class.php file just to store functions only.

I changed `lastvote()` and `update_last()` function to static function and getting `true` and `false` on frontend. From where according to the conditions I am calling required functions and returning the results.